# How to retrieve metadata for return values of an sql server stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql-server, code-generation, metadata

I want to analyze an SQL Server stored procedure from .NET code to retrieve metadata for the data/columns it returns (not OUTPUT parameters). Like when you drag/drop a sp on a DataSet i VisualStudio and it automatically generates columns. It could be useful for me for some code generation I'm testing out.

The procedures contains simple select statements like SELECT a,b FROM c and I'd like to get metadata about a and b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SET FMTONLY ON` (and execute it) - but this is a bit hit-n-miss. It doesn't cover all scenarios (branches, etc) - and can still execute some code (extended stored procedures etc).

Alternatively - use table-valued-functions (udfs) - they have much richer/more-formal metadata.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012 /Denali you can use [`sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878236%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

This returns information about the first result set in the procedure (as long as this result set is returned by all code paths)